# Divide algorithm for binary number with run time of O(logn)

Tags: binary, division

I need to write in simple assembly language (not assembly syntax) a program that calculates the division of two binary numbers of 16 bits without a reminder in O(logn), and I wondered if there is an efficient algorithm to do it.

If found some algorithms on the web, but all of them are looking for access to specific bit in the number, and I can't do it..

The only arithmetic operations I have are +, -, shift right/left but only ones each operation, &, |, ! and thats all apparently..

Thanks,

Eliav

Answer (score 0):

this should work.
does it help you?

C-Style:

```
c=1;
// find the maximum n for b*2^n <= a
// c=2^n
while((b << 1) <= a) {
    b = b << 1;
    c = c << 1;
}
while (c > 0) {
    if (a - b >= 0) {
        a -= b;
        result += c;
    }
    c = c >> 1;
    b = b >> 1;
}
```

Assembly-Style:

```
registers s0,s1,s2,s3, zero
syntax <instr.> <dest>,<src>,<arg>

%result: s0
%a: s1
%b: s2
%c: s3

add, s3, zero, 1



loop_1_start:
left_shift s4,s2,1
jump_if_greater s4,s1,loop_1_end

left_shift s2,s2,1
left_shift s3,s3,1

jump loop_1_start
loop_1_end:

loop_2_start:
jump_if_greate_or_equal s3,zero,loop_2_end

if_start:
sub s4,s1,s2
jump_if_smaller s4, zero, if_end
sub s1,s1,s2
add s0,s0,s3
if_end:


right_shift s2,s2,1
right_shift s3,s3,1

jump loop_2_start
loop_2_end:
```